# How to merge three columns (where 2 are always null) into one new column in Knex/Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

So I have an entity in my database that is linked to one of three assets.

It's currently implemented in a straightforward way, using three columns in the table (asset1_id, asset2_id, asset3_id) of which two will always be null and one will be populated with the selected asset.

For searching and ordering purposes, I would love to be able to create an extra column that merges the data from those three asset columns.

If at all possible, it should disregard the two null values and then use the name field of the one populated asset column as the value for this new calculated column.

I'm using Knex and I have seen there was a .union function but I am not sure how to use it to create an extra column which this calculated result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please can add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: In plain SQL you can use: `coalesce(asset1_id, asset2_id, asset3_id)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Would I be able to name that result 'asset' and use it to perform searches/ordering?

Right now, I already do this:   

```baseQuery.modify(queryBuilder => queryBuilder.leftJoinRelation('[hydrant, valve, generalAsset]'));```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Knex at all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're experiencing some pain from not normalising your data earlier. This is fine, it just means you might want to consider a bit of an 'upgrade'.

### Or maybe a ONE to MANY?

Based on your comments on this answer, you may like to arrange things in this way:

```
╔════════════════════╗
║ users              ║
╠═══════╦════════════╣
║ id    ║ increments ║
║ name  ║ string     ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝

╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ jobs                                         ║
╠═════════════╦════════════════════════════════╣
║ id          ║ increments                     ║
║ description ║ string                         ║
║ asset_id    ║ integer (references assets.id) ║
║ user_id     ║ integer (references users.id)  ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝

╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ assets                                                       ║
╠════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ id                 ║ increments                              ║
║ name               ║ string                                  ║
║ characteristics_id ║ integer (references characteristics.id) ║
╚════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════╝

╔══════════════════════════════╗
║ characteristics              ║
╠═════════════════╦════════════╣
║ id              ║ increments ║
║ description     ║ string     ║
║ hasPulleys      ║ boolean    ║
║ hasLevers       ║ boolean    ║
║ colour          ║ enum       ║
║ configuration   ║ jsonb      ║
╚═════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Of course, if the set of asset characteristics isn't too huge, you could just put them all in the `assets` table and deal with the fact that some will be `NULL` depending on the asset. It's over to you... investigating the `JSON/JSONB` column types may be helpful.

#### Querying

To get a job and its asset, you'd query like so:

```
db('jobs')
  .join('assets', 'jobs.asset_id', 'assets.id')
  .join('characteristics', 'assets.characteristics_id', 'characteristics.id')
  .select('jobs.description', 'assets.name', 'characteristics.hasPulleys')
```

or whichever columns you require.

### For posterity: how to get the column name

Although I guess you *can* put a column name in a column, it's a bit of a 'code smell'... makes you think there might be a better solution for what you're trying to accomplish. We'd need to hear more about your current schema and the problem to be solved.

If you're really, *truly* sure that it's what you want, here's how you could get the name of the column whose value is not null:

```
db.with(
  "col_names",
  db.unionAll([
    db
      .select(db.raw("id, 'asset_1' as col_name"))
      .from("users")
      .whereNotNull("asset_1"),
    db
      .select(db.raw("id, 'asset_2' as col_name"))
      .from("users")
      .whereNotNull("asset_2"),
    db
      .select(db.raw("id, 'asset_3' as col_name"))
      .from("users")
      .whereNotNull("asset_3")
  ])
)
  .select("col_name")
  .from("col_names")
  .where("id", userId)
```

or whatever id you're searching against. It should be stressed that this is not a flexible or future-proof solution.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response!

As for your question, I am aware it's a bit of a naive implementation but I am no expert on SQL or database design, so for now, I felt it sufficed. 

The entity I am linking to is a job. This job has a user that needs to perform the job and an asset, which can be one of three different distinct assets. These assets share an interface but have different other characteristics and are thus saved in three different tables and linked to the job as three possible relations. Two of which will always be null.

Not sure if that helps?

Comment: So I guess it would be a one-to-many? A job can always have one asset but an asset can have multiple jobs. The problem is that there can be three types of assets.

Comment: I wasn't trying to criticise you BTW, just pointing out alternatives :) so the question you need to ask is, will a job _always_ have only three possible assets? And will a job always only have one asset in total? You may find your schema is simpler than you expect... a jobs table, assets table, and perhaps some sort of characteristics table to differentiate them. It's unlikely you need a table for each kind of asset, especially if there are only three in total. I'll sketch something up in an edit to demonstrate.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't feel offended haha. And you'd be right to criticize me. It is difficult to see what's a good approach in terms of database design. Like, I was sure I needed three tables, one for each asset, but now you show me a totally different approach which also seems quite interesting and would help me out quite a bit, but it's difficult to weigh the pros and cons. Is there any material/resource you could point me to to learn a bit more about this topic? Thanks again for all your help :)